# Invalid object name, SQL Exception. Nothing fixes it!

Tags: c#, sql

So, I have been trying to fix this for about two months.  It all started when my "dev" machine went kaput and I set it up on my laptop.  It was working fun on my old PC but, it does not work on my new PC and never did on laptop.

I structured the SQL Server as much like the first one as I could remember but, it started giving me SQLExceptions.  I googled it, I searched on here for it, I tried different solutions.  Nothing.

I will post the offending code and I am hoping someone will be able to help me see my flaw.  I am sure it is something stupid.

```
   SqlCommand sc = sqlc.CreateCommand();
                sc.CommandText = "SELECT pNumber FROM database WHERE pNumber = '" + Number.ToString() + "'";
                SqlDataReader sdr = sc.ExecuteReader();
                if (sdr.Read().ToString() != null)
                {
                    sdr.Close();
                   sc.CommandText = "UPDATE word SET word = '" + Word + "' WHERE pNumber = '" + Number.ToString() + "'";
                   HERE IS WHERE THE ERROR OCCURS---->  sc.ExecuteReader();
                }
                else
                {
                    sdr.Close();
                    sc.CommandText = "INSERT INTO database VALUES(" + Number.ToString() + ",'" + Word + "',0, 0, 0)";
                    sc.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    sc.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM database WHERE pNumber = '" + Number.ToString() + "'";
                    SqlDataReader dataRead = sc.ExecuteReader();
                    for (int x = 0; x < 6; ++x)
                    {
                        User[x] = dataRead.GetString(x);
                    }
                }
                sqlc.Close();
```

EDIT:  SqlException: Invalid object name: 'word'. 
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(...

Comment: **WHERE** and **WHAT** exceptions do you get?? Did you step through the code? What is the problematic line?

Comment: Please post the text of the exception you get.  Also, try constructing the SQL you're trying to execute, execute it by hand in SQL Workbench, and see what you get.

Comment: Haha.  Sorry about that Marc, I was not thinking when I said Line 120.  :3

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
sc.CommandText = "UPDATE word SET word = '" + Word + "' WHERE pNumber = '" + Number.ToString() + "'";
```

should probably read

```
sc.CommandText = "UPDATE database SET word = '" + Word + "' WHERE pNumber = '" + Number.ToString() + "'";
```

I changed the tablename in the SQL query, that is all.

Comment: Michael said it in a comment but, you got to it right as I discovered it from what Michael said.  Silly me.

Every time I post, it is a silly error on my part.

Answer (score 6):

Change your input values to parameters. It's much safer, and might fix your issue if it's a problem caused by accidental SQL injection.

http://www.csharp-station.com/Tutorials/AdoDotNet/Lesson06.aspx

Like this:

```
sc.CommandText = "INSERT INTO database VALUES(@number,@word,0, 0, 0)";
sc.Parameters.Add("@number", SqlType.Int).Value = number;
sc.Parameters.Add("@word", SqlType.Int).Value = Word
```

Answer (score 2):

Where your code reads

```
sc.CommandText = "SELECT pNumber FROM database WHERE pNumber = '" + Number.ToString() + "'";
```

does that mean your user-defined database is actually named "database"? The word "database" is a reserved word, and this could be causing you grief.